# Почему последний div переходит на следующую строку?

Tags: html, css

Нужно чтобы div'ы были в одной строке, но последний div переносится на следующую строку и выходит за пределы класса explore. Если уменьшить масштаб в браузере, то элементы помещаются в одной строке.
**HTML:**

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="explore padding-site">
            <div class="explore-controll clearfix">
                <ul class="explore-controll-menu">
                    <li class="explore-controll-item"><a class="explore-controll-link-active" href="#">Featured  </a></li>
                    <li class="explore-controll-item"><a class="explore-controll-link" href="#">  New  </a></li>
                </ul>
                <a class="explore-controll-all" href="#">explore all <img class="explore-arrow" src="src/img/arrow.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="explore-product">
                    <img class="explore-product-image" src="src/img/product-1.jpg" alt="Product 1">
                    <div class="explore-product-hover">
                        <a class="explore-product-hover-circle" href="#"><img class="explore-arrow-hover" src="src/img/arrow.png" alt=""></a>
                        <h3 class="explore-product-hover-h3">Fishnet Chair</h3>
                        <p class="explore-product-hover-text">Seat and back with upholstery made of cold cure foam</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="explore-product">
                    <img class="explore-product-image" src="src/img/product-2.jpg" alt="Product 2">
                    <div class="explore-product-hover">
                        <a class="explore-product-hover-circle" href="#"><img class="explore-arrow" src="src/img/arrow.png" alt=""></a>
                        <h3 class="explore-product-hover-h3">Fishnet Chair</h3>
                        <p class="explore-product-hover-text">Seat and back with upholstery made of cold cure foam</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="explore-product">
                    <img class="explore-product-image" src="src/img/product-3.jpg" alt="Product 3">
                    <div class="explore-product-hover">
                        <a class="explore-product-hover-circle" href="#"><img class="explore-arrow" src="src/img/arrow.png" alt=""></a>
                        <h3 class="explore-product-hover-h3">Fishnet Chair</h3>
                        <p class="explore-product-hover-text">Seat and back with upholstery made of cold cure foam</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="explore-product">
                    <img class="explore-product-image" src="src/img/product-4.jpg" alt="Product 4">
                    <div class="explore-product-hover">
                        <a class="explore-product-hover-circle" href="#"><img class="explore-arrow" src="src/img/arrow.png" alt=""></a>
                        <h3 class="explore-product-hover-h3">Fishnet Chair</h3>
                        <p class="explore-product-hover-text">Seat and back with upholstery made of cold cure foam</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.padding-site {
    padding-left: 98px;
    padding-right: 98px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.explore {
    height: 609px;
    position: absolute;
}

.explore-controll {
    padding-top: 120px;
}

.explore-controll-menu {
    float: left;
}

.explore-controll-item {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.explore-controll-link {
    display: block;
    color: #6c6c6c;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
}

.explore-controll-link-active {
    color: #212121;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #212121;
}

.explore-controll-all {
    float: right;
    color: #212121;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3.6px;
}

.explore-arrow {
    width: 9px;
    height: 12px;
}

.explore-arrow-hover {
    width: 12px;
    height: 20px;
}

.explore-product {
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
    height: 270px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.explore-product-hover-circle {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.35);
    border-radius: 24px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.explore-product-hover-h3 {
    color: #212121;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 29.88px;
}

.explore-product-hover-text {
    color: #6c6c6c;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 21.91px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у Вас фиксированная ширина блоков, и когда она перестает влазить в ширину - перепрыгивает на след. строку.

Как вариант - указать ширину в процентах.

В остальном Ваш код не правил, но тут много чего стоит написать написать совершенно иначе. Зачем-то вы используете `absolute` у `.explore`. Советую просто его внимательно переписать.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.padding-site {
    padding-left: 98px;
    padding-right: 98px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.explore {
    height: 609px;
    position: absolute;
}

.explore-controll {
    padding-top: 120px;
}

.explore-controll-menu {
    float: left;
}

.explore-controll-item {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.explore-controll-link {
    display: block;
    color: #6c6c6c;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
}

.explore-controll-link-active {
    color: #212121;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #212121;
}

.explore-controll-all {
    float: right;
    color: #212121;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3.6px;
}

.explore-arrow {
    width: 9px;
    height: 12px;
}

.explore-arrow-hover {
    width: 12px;
    height: 20px;
}

.explore-product {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 270px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.explore-product-hover-circle {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.35);
    border-radius: 24px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.explore-product-hover-h3 {
    color: #212121;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 29.88px;
}

.explore-product-hover-text {
    color: #6c6c6c;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 21.91px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="explore padding-site">
            <div class="explore-controll clearfix">
                <ul class="explore-controll-menu">
                    <li class="explore-controll-item"><a class="explore-controll-link-active" href="#">Featured  </a></li>
                    <li class="explore-controll-item"><a class="explore-controll-link" href="#">  New  </a></li>
                </ul>
                <a class="explore-controll-all" href="#">explore all <img class="explore-arrow" src="src/img/arrow.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="explore-product">
                    <img class="explore-product-image" src="src/img/product-1.jpg" alt="Product 1">
                    <div class="explore-product-hover">
                        <a class="explore-product-hover-circle" href="#"><img class="explore-arrow-hover" src="src/img/arrow.png" alt=""></a>
                        <h3 class="explore-product-hover-h3">Fishnet Chair</h3>
                        <p class="explore-product-hover-text">Seat and back with upholstery made of cold cure foam</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="explore-product">
                    <img class="explore-product-image" src="src/img/product-2.jpg" alt="Product 2">
                    <div class="explore-product-hover">
                        <a class="explore-product-hover-circle" href="#"><img class="explore-arrow" src="src/img/arrow.png" alt=""></a>
                        <h3 class="explore-product-hover-h3">Fishnet Chair</h3>
                        <p class="explore-product-hover-text">Seat and back with upholstery made of cold cure foam</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="explore-product">
                    <img class="explore-product-image" src="src/img/product-3.jpg" alt="Product 3">
                    <div class="explore-product-hover">
                        <a class="explore-product-hover-circle" href="#"><img class="explore-arrow" src="src/img/arrow.png" alt=""></a>
                        <h3 class="explore-product-hover-h3">Fishnet Chair</h3>
                        <p class="explore-product-hover-text">Seat and back with upholstery made of cold cure foam</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="explore-product">
                    <img class="explore-product-image" src="src/img/product-4.jpg" alt="Product 4">
                    <div class="explore-product-hover">
                        <a class="explore-product-hover-circle" href="#"><img class="explore-arrow" src="src/img/arrow.png" alt=""></a>
                        <h3 class="explore-product-hover-h3">Fishnet Chair</h3>
                        <p class="explore-product-hover-text">Seat and back with upholstery made of cold cure foam</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```